# Is there a formula to extract multiple values of a cell and paste them in the same count of rows along with the rest of the row's contents?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have this:

[image]

And I want to display the data according to the "Access To" column separated by each Account #
like this:

[image]

and let's say we have multiple users, is there a way when running this script to repeat the same for all the users and create as many rows as their "Access to" account numbers?

So far I have done it only for one user with a very manual process combining `ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT()))` but I can't figure out how to make it continue with the next user of the list.

Here is the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zGj3l7aA2iC0xc52IFnw80RrN5sVWqgHn3-HXx539fg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: Hey @player0, here you go:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zGj3l7aA2iC0xc52IFnw80RrN5sVWqgHn3-HXx539fg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see your sheet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
={'Current Version'!A1:I1;
 ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT('Current Version'!H2:H, ";"))<>"", "♦"&'Current Version'!A2:A&
 "♥"&'Current Version'!B2:B&"♥"&'Current Version'!C2:C&"♥"&'Current Version'!D2:D&
 "♥"&'Current Version'!E2:E&"♥"&'Current Version'!F2:F&"♥"&'Current Version'!G2:G&
 "♥"&TRIM(SPLIT('Current Version'!H2:H, ";"))&"♥"&'Current Version'!I2:I, ))
 ,,99^99)),,99^99), "♦")), "♥"))}
```

[image: 0]